# Contract transaction cannot be found after i get result of pushSignedTransaction

Tags: smart-contract, transactions

I've send a contract trans on mainnet use eosjs@20, and i've tried for 4 times, every time i get a trans result, but all of them seemed been drop, i cannot find them on explorer or on chain, can any one help to explain this?
And i send to the NO 1 BP node, huobi.

```
{        
 transaction_id:'8539aa984de2c9fb0e6387dc2e2633503c1875a83ca034c66b3bed329bd3d6fb',
       processed:{ 
          id:'8539aa984de2c9fb0e6387dc2e2633503c1875a83ca034c66b3bed329bd3d6fb',
          block_num:104699332,
          block_time:'2020-02-12T01:39:25.500',
          producer_block_id:null,
          receipt:{ 
             status:'executed',
             cpu_usage_us:26133,
             net_usage_words:65
          },
          elapsed:26133,
          net_usage:520,
          scheduled:false,
          #12 action_traces:[ 
             [ 
                Object
             ]
          ],
          account_ram_delta:null,
          except:null,
          error_code:null
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The result you get after sending transaction doesn't guarantee this transaction to be included in the block. When node receives a transaction, it tries executing transaction with current state. If it is executed normally, node will return locally executed result immediately to sender and broadcast transaction to other BPs. However, because of various reasons (network partition, missing block production, etc), it can fail to make transaction included in the block.

Comment: How can we confirm if the transaction is included in the block?

Comment: @Muhzin After sending tx, you should monitor following blocks whether your tx is included. If you find your tx from a block and its status is changed to irreversible, you can say it's confirmed. You can use [demux](https://github.com/EOSIO/demux-js) or history solutions like dfuse, hyperion etc.